# Mule ESB: DOM-to-XML parser thows xml parser error when xml element has angles brackets in it

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, mule, mule-component

I have an input xml like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sendRequest">
   <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:Message>
          <urn:id> 12345 </urn:id>
          <urn:name> srinath </urn:name>
          <urn:body> >Hello< </urn:body>
        </urn:Message>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Mule ESB DOM-to-XMl transformer gives error when it encounter '>' and '<' in tags. How do I escape this? Entering &lt etc not an option since end users wont be knowledgible.

The error thrown is:
    Message : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected  character '<' (code 60) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [9,26] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException)
    Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Any work around is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it 2 ways :-

- Either use `&lt;Hello&gt;`
- or use cdata like :- `<![CDATA[ >Hello<]]>`

So your input xml will be :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sendRequest">
   <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:Message>
          <urn:id> 12345 </urn:id>
          <urn:name> srinath </urn:name>
          <urn:body> &lt;Hello&gt; </urn:body>
  <!-- or use this <urn:body> <![CDATA[ >Hello<]]> </urn:body> -->
        </urn:Message>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight; By this you mean the user has to type in these notations and there is no way we can replace the text programmatically before it hits the DOM transformer?

Comment: It depends on how you provide the request to the webservice .. If you are using SOAPUI, you can type the input in the request .. you can replace the text programmatically if you are exposing the service in Mule and implementing the webservice interface ... You can controll you input and modify/add notations of input data in service layer in the implementation class .. We need to look your Mule config for that ...

Answer (score 3):

Well of course it does. That's what XML parsers are for. If you give them stuff that isn't well-formed XML, they complain.

XML is unforgiving. Don't imagine that you can create something that looks roughly like XML and someone will sort out the mess. It's like a programming language: if you don't follow the grammar, it won't compile.

You say "Entering &lt etc not an option since end users wont be knowledgible." Well, if you can't train your end users to produce valid XML, then you shouldn't be asking them to do so. You should give them an XML editor (e.g. OXygen Author) that hides the details, or you should use a simpler and more forgiving format like Markdown.

Comment: Atleast can we replace these "<" occurances with &gt;/&lt; etc before it gets validated in DOM parser programmatically?

Comment: Only if you know how to distinguish an angle bracket in content from one that's markup.